# My yahoo finance quotes won't update accordingly

Tags: api, rest, yahoo, finance

My yahoo finance quotes don't update accordingly even though the quotes are streaming. Using chrome gives me updates from 9:00am, however using firefox gives me updates at 2:25pm using the same query. At yahoo I can even see that the stocks are up and streaming. After I request the information a third time in firefox the quotes are for some reason reversed back to 9:00am this morning.

What can cause this? The developer forum for yql is down/unreachable so I'm hoping someone here can help me.

[LINK TO FULL QUERY](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20ChangeinPercent%2C%20Name%2C%20LastTradeDate%2C%20Symbol%2C%20DaysLow%2C%20DaysHigh%2C%20LastTradePriceOnly%2C%20LastTradeTime%2C%20Volume%2C%20Open%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%27ORTI-B.ST%27%2C%20%27POOL-B.ST%27%2C%20%27PREC.ST%27%2C%20%27PREV-B.ST%27%2C%20%27PRIC-B.ST%27%2C%20%27PACT.ST%27%2C%20%27PROB.ST%27%2C%20%27PROF-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ORTI-A.ST%27%2C%20%27OPCO.ST%27%2C%20%27ODD.ST%27%2C%20%27NTEK-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NOVE.ST%27%2C%20%27NOTE.ST%27%2C%20%27NSP-B.ST%27%2C%20%27RAY-B.ST%27%2C%20%27VSSAB-B.ST%27%2C%20%27REJL-B.ST%27%2C%20%27RNBS.ST%27%2C%20%27RROS.ST%27%2C%20%27SEAM.ST%27%2C%20%27SEMC.ST%27%2C%20%27SENS.ST%27%2C%20%27SINT.ST%27%2C%20%27SOF-B.ST%27%2C%20%27STWK.ST%27%2C%20%27SVIK.ST%27%2C%20%27SVED-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SVOL-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SVOL-B.ST%27%2C%20%27TRAC-B.ST%27%2C%20%27TRAD.ST%27%2C%20%27TAGR.ST%27%2C%20%27UFLX-B.ST%27%2C%20%27VRG-B.ST%27%2C%20%27VIT-B.ST%27%2C%20%27XANO-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ACAN-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ANOD-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ATRLJ-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ALNX.ST%27%2C%20%27ATEL-A.ST%27%2C%20%27ANOT.ST%27%2C%20%27ARP.ST%27%2C%20%27ARISE.ST%27%2C%20%27DOM.ST%27%2C%20%27AVEG-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BEGR.ST%27%2C%20%27BELE.ST%27%2C%20%27BRG-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BESQ.ST%27%2C%20%27BINV.ST%27%2C%20%27BIOT.ST%27%2C%20%27BORG.ST%27%2C%20%27BEF-SDB.ST%27%2C%20%27BONG.ST%27%2C%20%27BOUL.ST%27%2C%20%27BTS-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BULTEN.ST%27%2C%20%27CRAD-B.ST%27%2C%20%27CEVI.ST%27%2C%20%27CCOR-B.ST%27%2C%20%27CONS-B.ST%27%2C%20%27CTT.ST%27%2C%20%27DEDI.ST%27%2C%20%27DGC.ST%27%2C%20%27DORO.ST%27%2C%20%27DURC-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ELAN-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ELEC.ST%27%2C%20%27ELOS-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ENDO.ST%27%2C%20%27ENEA.ST%27%2C%20%27EOLU-B.ST%27%2C%20%27EPIS-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ETX.ST%27%2C%20%27EWRK.ST%27%2C%20%27FEEL.ST%27%2C%20%27FPIP.ST%27%2C%20%27G5EN.ST%27%2C%20%27HUFV-C.ST%27%2C%20%27GHP.ST%27%2C%20%27HAV-B.ST%27%2C%20%27PNDX-B.ST%27%2C%20%27IAR-B.ST%27%2C%20%27IS.ST%27%2C%20%27ICTA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27KABE-B.ST%27%2C%20%27KARO.ST%27%2C%20%27KDEV.ST%27%2C%20%27KNOW.ST%27%2C%20%27LAMM-B.ST%27%2C%20%27MEAB-B.ST%27%2C%20%27MSAB-B.ST%27%2C%20%27MSON-A.ST%27%2C%20%27MSON-B.ST%27%2C%20%27MIDW-A.ST%27%2C%20%27MIDW-B.ST%27%2C%20%27MOB.ST%27%2C%20%27MQ.ST%27%2C%20%27MSC-B.ST%27%2C%20%27MULQ.ST%27%2C%20%27NAXS.ST%27%2C%20%27NETI-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NVP.ST%27%2C%20%27NOMI.ST%27%2C%20%27AAK.ST%27%2C%20%27ABB.ST%27%2C%20%27AOI.ST%27%2C%20%27ALFA.ST%27%2C%20%27ASSA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27AZN.ST%27%2C%20%27ATCO-A.ST%27%2C%20%27ATCO-B.ST%27%2C%20%27WALL-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ALIV-SDB.ST%27%2C%20%27AXFO.ST%27%2C%20%27AXIS.ST%27%2C%20%27BETS-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BILL.ST%27%2C%20%27BOL.ST%27%2C%20%27CAST.ST%27%2C%20%27COMH.ST%27%2C%20%27ELUX-A.ST%27%2C%20%27ELUX-B.ST%27%2C%20%27EKTA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ENQ.ST%27%2C%20%27ERIC-A.ST%27%2C%20%27ERIC-B.ST%27%2C%20%27FABG.ST%27%2C%20%27BALD-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BALD-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27GETI-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SHB-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SHB-B.ST%27%2C%20%27HM-B.ST%27%2C%20%27HEXA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27HPOL-B.ST%27%2C%20%27HOLM-A.ST%27%2C%20%27HOLM-B.ST%27%2C%20%27HUFV-A.ST%27%2C%20%27HUSQ-A.ST%27%2C%20%27HUSQ-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ICA.ST%27%2C%20%27INDU-A.ST%27%2C%20%27INDU-C.ST%27%2C%20%27INDT.ST%27%2C%20%27IJ.ST%27%2C%20%27INVE-A.ST%27%2C%20%27INVE-B.ST%27%2C%20%27JM.ST%27%2C%20%27KINV-A.ST%27%2C%20%27KINV-B.ST%27%2C%20%27LATO-B.ST%27%2C%20%27LIFCO-B.ST%27%2C%20%27LOOM-B.ST%27%2C%20%27LUND-B.ST%27%2C%20%27LUMI-SDB.ST%27%2C%20%27LUPE.ST%27%2C%20%27MEDA-A.ST%27%2C%20%27MELK.ST%27%2C%20%27MIC-SDB.ST%27%2C%20%27MTG-A.ST%27%2C%20%27MTG-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NCC-A.ST%27%2C%20%27NCC-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NIBE-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NOBI.ST%27%2C%20%27NDA-SEK.ST%27%2C%20%27WISE.ST%27%2C%20%27PEAB-B.ST%27%2C%20%27RATO-A.ST%27%2C%20%27RATO-B.ST%27%2C%20%27RATO-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27SAAB-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SAND.ST%27%2C%20%27SCA-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SCA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SEB-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SEB-C.ST%27%2C%20%27SECU-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SKA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SKF-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SKF-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SSAB-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SSAB-B.ST%27%2C%20%27STE-A.ST%27%2C%20%27STE-R.ST%27%2C%20%27SWED-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SWMA.ST%27%2C%20%27SOBI.ST%27%2C%20%27TEL2-A.ST%27%2C%20%27TEL2-B.ST%27%2C%20%27TLSN.ST%27%2C%20%27TIEN.ST%27%2C%20%27TREL-B.ST%27%2C%20%27VOLV-A.ST%27%2C%20%27VOLV-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ACTI.ST%27%2C%20%27ADDT-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ARCM.ST%27%2C%20%27AZA.ST%27%2C%20%27BBTO-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BACTI-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BEIA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BEIJ-B.ST%27%2C%20%27BILI-A.ST%27%2C%20%27BIOG-B.ST%27%2C%20%27PXXS-SDB.ST%27%2C%20%27BUFAB.ST%27%2C%20%27BURE.ST%27%2C%20%27BMAX.ST%27%2C%20%27CATE.ST%27%2C%20%27CCC.ST%27%2C%20%27CLA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27CLAS-B.ST%27%2C%20%27COIC.ST%27%2C%20%27CORE.ST%27%2C%20%27CORE-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27CRED-A.ST%27%2C%20%27DIOS.ST%27%2C%20%27DUNI.ST%27%2C%20%27DUST.ST%27%2C%20%27ECEX.ST%27%2C%20%27ELTEL.ST%27%2C%20%27ENRO.ST%27%2C%20%27ENRO-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27FAG.ST%27%2C%20%27FPAR.ST%27%2C%20%27FPAR-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27FOI-B.ST%27%2C%20%27FING-B.ST%27%2C%20%27GRNG.ST%27%2C%20%27GUNN.ST%27%2C%20%27HLDX.ST%27%2C%20%27HEBA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27HEMF.ST%27%2C%20%27HEMF-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27HIQ.ST%27%2C%20%27HMS.ST%27%2C%20%27IFS-A.ST%27%2C%20%27IFS-B.ST%27%2C%20%27INWI.ST%27%2C%20%27ITAB-B.ST%27%2C%20%27KAHL.ST%27%2C%20%27KLOV-A.ST%27%2C%20%27KLOV-B.ST%27%2C%20%27KLOV-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27KLED.ST%27%2C%20%27LAGR-B.ST%27%2C%20%27LIAB.ST%27%2C%20%27LUC.ST%27%2C%20%27LUG.ST%27%2C%20%27MVIR-B.ST%27%2C%20%27MEKO.ST%27%2C%20%27MUNK1S.ST%27%2C%20%27NDX.ST%27%2C%20%27ORI.ST%27%2C%20%27SHOT.ST%27%2C%20%27THULE.ST%27%2C%20%27TOBII.ST%27%2C%20%27TROAX.ST%27%2C%20%27VNV-SDB.ST%27%2C%20%27NMAN.ST%27%2C%20%27NET-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NEWA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NGQ.ST%27%2C%20%27NOLA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NN-B.ST%27%2C%20%27NP3.ST%27%2C%20%27OASM.ST%27%2C%20%27OEM-B.ST%27%2C%20%27OPUS.ST%27%2C%20%27ORX.ST%27%2C%20%27PLAZ-B.ST%27%2C%20%27PROE-B.ST%27%2C%20%27QLRO.ST%27%2C%20%27RECI-B.ST%27%2C%20%27REZT.ST%27%2C%20%27SAGA-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SAGA-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SAGA-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27SCST.ST%27%2C%20%27SPOR.ST%27%2C%20%27SAS.ST%27%2C%20%27SAS-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27SECT-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SMF.ST%27%2C%20%27SKIS-B.ST%27%2C%20%27COOR.ST%27%2C%20%27DCAR-B.ST%27%2C%20%27HOFI.ST%27%2C%20%27IVSO.ST%27%2C%20%27MYCR.ST%27%2C%20%27NOBINA.ST%27%2C%20%27SWEC-A.ST%27%2C%20%27SWEC-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SWOL-B.ST%27%2C%20%27SYSR.ST%27%2C%20%27TETY.ST%27%2C%20%27TWW.ST%27%2C%20%27OP.ST%27%2C%20%27ALIG.ST%27%2C%20%27ATT.ST%27%2C%20%27BRAV.ST%27%2C%20%27CAMX.ST%27%2C%20%27HTRO.ST%27%2C%20%27HMED.ST%27%2C%20%27OP-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27TRI.ST%27%2C%20%27UNIB-SDB.ST%27%2C%20%27VBG-B.ST%27%2C%20%27VICP-A.ST%27%2C%20%27VICP-B.ST%27%2C%20%27VICP-PREF.ST%27%2C%20%27VITR.ST%27%2C%20%27CLX.ST%27%2C%20%27WIHL.ST%27%2C%20%27AF-B.ST%27%2C%20%27ORES.ST%27%2C%20%27COLL.ST%27%29&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

**Code Snippet**

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="321" yahoo:created="2016-03-09T11:45:53Z" yahoo:lang="en-us">
   <results>
      <quote>
        <LastTradeDate>3/9/2016</LastTradeDate>
        <DaysLow>2.77</DaysLow>
        <DaysHigh>2.77</DaysHigh>
        <LastTradePriceOnly>2.77</LastTradePriceOnly>
        <Name>ORTIVUS -B-</Name>
        <Open>2.77</Open>
        <ChangeinPercent>+1.84%</ChangeinPercent>
        <Symbol>ORTI-B.ST</Symbol>
        <LastTradeTime>9:59am</LastTradeTime>
        <Volume>500</Volume>
      </quote>
      <quote>
        <LastTradeDate>3/9/2016</LastTradeDate>
        <DaysLow>13.40</DaysLow>
        <DaysHigh>14.00</DaysHigh>
        <LastTradePriceOnly>14.00</LastTradePriceOnly>
        <Name>POOLIA -B-</Name>
        <Open>13.65</Open>
        <ChangeinPercent>-1.41%</ChangeinPercent>
        <Symbol>POOL-B.ST</Symbol>
        <LastTradeTime>11:44am</LastTradeTime>
        <Volume>1353</Volume>
      </quote>
```

Comment: I am seeing the same behaviour. Calling the same query for just one stock symbol returns different trade times. Have you been able to solve this issue by getting only the latest quotes?

Comment: Yes, I solved it by running another query that returned a .csv file. That way the content was allways updated.